# Given a positive integer $k$, find the positive integers $n$ for which $3^k \vert 2^n-1.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given a positive integer $k$, find the positive integers $n$ for which $3^k \vert 2^n-1.$

If $n$ is even we would have that $n=2t$ and since $3 \vert4-1=3$ we can use the LTE lemma.

So $v_3(2^n-1)=v_3(4^t-1)=v_3(4-1)+v_3(t)=1+v_3(t).$

A couple of questions. $(1)$ How can I be sure that $n$ has to be even, I cannot seem to be able to verify that.

$(2)$ Does it imply directly from LTE that every $1+v_3(t) \geqslant k$ will satisfy the given condition?

Comment: Since $2\equiv -1 \pmod 3$, we see that $2^n\equiv 1\pmod 3\iff (-1)^n\equiv 1 \pmod 3\implies n$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

$2$ is a primitive root mod $3^k$ for all $k$. In particular, the multiplicative order of $2$ mod $3^k$ is $\phi(3^k)=2\cdot 3^{k-1}$. Therefore, $2^n \equiv 1 \bmod 3^k$ iff $n$ is a multiple of $2\cdot 3^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

- For the first question, suppose $n$ is odd.

    Then since
    $2\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;3)$
    , we get
    $$
    2^n-1
    \equiv
    (-1)^n-1
    \equiv
    -1-1
    \equiv
    -2
    \;(\text{mod}\;3)
    $$
    so
    $3^k$
    doesn't divide
    $2^n-1$
    .
    $\\[10pt]$

  For the second question, yes, if $n=2t$ then
  $$
  3^k{\,\mid\,}(2^n-1)
  \iff
  v_3(2^n-1)\ge k
  \iff
  1+v_3(t)\ge k
  $$